# SQL - Select highest value from table where the value matches a format?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have a `variable` that returns a `format` something like `variable = '10100001001'`

I want to select the highest value(max) from a `column` (char 20) where the value matches the format of the above variable.

Matches -- might be the `length`, etc.,

I have seen similar kind of questions to select the max value but not matches a format.

So something like `Select value from Table1 where value like ('%variable%')`

I would like to know is there any more obvious and elegant way to get this.

### sample data:

```
id    value
--  -- -- -- --
1   101000019
2   abcd123gh 
3   101000026 
4   abcd
5    23433
6   10100gh34
```

### Desired results:

```
101000026
```

Thanks

Comment: Sample data, desired results... You should know this by now!

Comment: Sorry @zoharpeled. Updated the question.

Comment: What in case no matching result? Assume I am looking for 2412e11, what is your expected result?

Comment: I don't know if your expected results will be correct with 101000026 in the example above. Since your like '%variable%' will bring in ID 1,3 and 6. In this particular sample, what is the MAX value? Since you have a Num and VARCHAR stored on the same column. Do you only want the MAX of a NUM?

Comment: Could you up update your sample data layout - looks like 'value' is 4 columns of length=2, id=5 looks like value has a leading blank - ' 23433'; and what is the variable/format you're using to generate the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Not sure what you mean by "Matches -- might be the `length`", so ignoring that tidbit for time being ...

If all you're doing is a `like` pattern match you can just append the `%` on the ends of @variable, either by updating the variable (`select @variable = '%' + @variable + '%'`) or in the WHERE clause (see below).

Here's a quick example ...

Setup:

```
create table Table1 (id int, value varchar(20))
go

insert Table1 values (1,'101000019')
insert Table1 values (2,'abcd123gh')
insert Table1 values (3,'101000026')
insert Table1 values (4,'abcd')
insert Table1 values (5,' 23433')
insert Table1 values (6,'10100gh34')
go

select * from Table1
go

 id          value
 ----------- --------------------
           1 101000019
           2 abcd123gh
           3 101000026
           4 abcd
           5  23433
           6 10100gh34
```

Example searches:

```
declare @variable varchar(20)

select  @variable = '10100001001'
print "++++++++++++ pattern : %1!", @variable
select max(value) from Table1 where value like '%' + @variable + '%'

select  @variable = '101000'
print "++++++++++++ pattern : %1!", @variable
select max(value) from Table1 where value like '%' + @variable + '%'

select  @variable = '10100'
print "++++++++++++ pattern : %1!", @variable
select max(value) from Table1 where value like '%' + @variable + '%'
go

++++++++++++ pattern : 10100001001
 max(Table1.value)
 --------------------
 NULL

++++++++++++ pattern : 101000
 max(Table1.value)
 --------------------
 101000026

++++++++++++ pattern : 10100
 max(Table1.value)
 --------------------
 10100gh34
```